# Can I run a shell built-in command with Puppet?

Tags: shell, puppet, command, execution

I want `~/.bashrc` will be `source` whenever changing its content. I created a bashrc class with something like this:

```
file { "/root/.bashrc":
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    mode    => 0644,
    source  => "puppet:///bashrc/root/.bashrc"
}

exec { "root_bashrc":
    command     => "source /root/.bashrc",
    subscribe   => File["/root/.bashrc"],
}
```

but as you know, `source` is a shell built-in command, thereforce I got the following error when running agent:

```
# puppet agent --no-daemonize --verbose
notice: Starting Puppet client version 2.7.1
info: Caching catalog for svr051-4170
info: Applying configuration version '1311563901'
err: /Stage[main]/Bashrc/Exec[root_bashrc]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command 'source'
notice: Finished catalog run in 2.28 seconds
notice: Caught INT; calling stop
```

Is there any workaround to do this?

Comment: Please help us understand what you're asking for; do you mean that you want Puppet to include the contents of "/root/.bashrc" whenever it uses the `exec` resource to make changes? I think you need to add more details about what overall goal you're trying to accomplish; the way you're going now is probably not going to work.

Comment: +1 for what handyman5 is saying

Comment: Sorry if my post is not clear enough. I mean I want to run `source ~/.bashrc` when its content is changed (just like when a configuration file is updated, you want to restart the corresponding service).

Comment: It doesn't makes sense to do that - you will need to restart the service that uses the environment anyway ( because it's environment is already loaded with the older bashrc )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no point in re-`source`ing a new `.bashrc` within Puppet, because it'll run in a subshell and the changes won't propagate into your current shell (which is, I assume, what you're trying to do).  You can't do what (I think) you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can also often preface your command with `true &&` or use `provider => shell`.

See [this](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4288) and [this](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4884) for additional discussion.

**This should be:**

```
file { "/root/.bashrc":
    ensure  => present,
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    mode    => 0644,
    source  => "puppet:///bashrc/root/.bashrc" }

exec { "root_bashrc":
    command     => "source /root/.bashrc",
    provider => shell,
    subscribe   => File["/root/.bashrc"], 
}
```

Comment: `provider` => 'shell'` looks like the best answer by far. But remember that `sh` is not `bash` therefore we should use `.` instead of `source`.

Comment: here is the actual issue that solved this, I think: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/4288#note-23

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you could use:

```
exec { "root_bashrc":
    command     => "bash -c 'source /root/.bashrc'",
    subscribe   => File["/root/.bashrc"],
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

However, as [@womble](https://serverfault.com/users/1375/womble) [already pointed out](https://serverfault.com/questions/293711/can-i-run-a-shell-built-in-command-with-puppet/293729#293729), there's no point in sourcing .bashrc like that; it only affects the bash shell that's run in that command, not any currently running bash shells.

You could possibly set `PROMPT_COMMAND="source /root/.bashrc"` to rerun the .bashrc every time a prompt is displayed in any currently running interactive shells, but that seems a bit resource intensive. I've never tried this, but I'd think it would work.